# How would I prevent access to a page in PHP without a url?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have a page called, "user.php". 
I want logged in users to only be able to access

user.php?user=username.

If someone types in user.php in their browser, I do not want them to see the general page that shows user.php without the url extension. Any tips? Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but your question seems incredibly unclear. Perhaps your just trying to check for `?user=` in your URL? You can check if they are passing that parameter by doing `isset($_GET['user'])`

Comment: in users.php, detect if you have a query string , ie `?user=username`, validate it, and redirect to a `soSorry.php` page if the query string is not to your liking : not there, no `user` parameter, etc...

Answer (score 3):

When user logs in you should store a user in the session.
And on the page 'user.php' you can have a function if the user exists in the session
then let him in, if it doesn't exist just redirect him.

Set session once user logs in

```
$_SESSION['logged'] = 'YouCanPutUsersNameHere';
```

Use this function on every page you want your user to be logged in.

```
function checkLogin() {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['logged'])) {
        header("location: /login");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: what a great comment ! now that you have sufficient rep, you should prefer a comment to an answer. If you answer, you should show substantive information on the help you are providing.

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve this by using $_SESSION

after the user login add

```
$_SESSION['logedin'] = '1';
```

and at the top of the user page add

```
   if ( $_SESSION['logedin'] !== '1' ) {
echo "Please Login to continue";
die();
 }
```

also don't forget to start or resume session on both login page and user page

```
 session_start()
```